# Docusign RecipientId getting set automatically

Tags: docusignapi

This is more of a sanity check for me. I am using the Rest api and I have a test app making the calls.  I created a template and added two signers, Signer1 and Signer2. I make a call to get my template from the template list for my account. I looked at the Recipients and I noticed that the two of them had RecipientId's already set, but I didn't set them. Just curious how Docusign sets these id's. I was seeing values like 91886879. The 2 signers, I just gave them the role names, did not give them email address.

Comment: Are you using a DocuSign SDK (if so, which platform?) or are you creating the REST requests from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're assigned arbitrarily when you create the template. You can choose to use those or override those with your own values; provided the role in the API call matches the role name in the template. When you implement a template by using the API those values are relative to the envelope only.